# Download file returned by js GET request with unique key

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm new to CasperJS.  Trying to download a cvs file from my bank.  In a standard browser you would click an "Ok" button and then receive the download.  The html for the button is:

```
<input type="button" id="dialogOk" class="yDialogOk" onclick="handleYes()" style="width:50px" value="OK">
```

When that is clicked a function makes the following GET request:

```
https://allmyaccounts.mybank.com/apps/export.obfbank.do?actionType=AllTransaction&c=csit_key%3A5L6bKL6bJaHY4ISx9AMG6yZY%2BSg%3D&l=u%3As
```

The response to that request has the follow properties:

```
Content-Disposition: Attachment; Filename="ExportData.csv"
```

I don't know how to download that ExportData.csv.  The methods I have found for downloading require you to have the target URL.  The problem I see is that the URL I need to target requires the csit_key property that is dynamically generated.  Once the current session is over the key stops working.  I looked all over the page source and resources but cannot find a reference to csit_key(even by another name) before the button is clicked.  It looks like I have to click that button to initiate the download.

I believe that casper/phantom cannot download a file that it did not specifically request.  Let me know if I'm wrong on that.  I found the following which I hoped might capture the download if ran right after/before the click but it never fires.  I never see those console.logs.

```
casper.on('page.resource.received', function(resource) {
    if (resource.stage !== "end") {
        console.log("resource.stage !== 'end'");
        return;
    }
    if (resource.url.indexOf('ExportData.csv') > -1) {
        console.log("Downloading csv file");
        this.download(resource.url, 'ExportData.csv');
    }
});
```

My next guess was to try and capture the generated GET after the click in order to extract the `csit_key`.  I could only find how to view response headers, not request headers.

I'm hoping someone can set me straight on how to download that csv file.

Comment: what version of the casperjs are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my event listener.  I was testing for the resource.url to have "ExportData.csv".  When I examined all received resources I saw the url and corrected the test.  The final test looked like this:

```
if (resource.url.indexOf('export.bofapfm.do') > -1) {
  console.log("Downloading csv file");
  this.download(resource.url, 'ExportData.csv');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the casperjs [documentation](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html) you should listen to the event 'resource.received' rather that 'page.resource.received'. So the code should look like following:

```
casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {
    if (resource.stage !== "end") {
        console.log("resource.stage !== 'end'");
        return;
    }
    if (resource.url.indexOf('ExportData.csv') > -1) {
        console.log("Downloading csv file");
        this.download(resource.url, 'ExportData.csv');
    }
});
```